# How can I assign my output to rows and columns?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am new to C# and I have a question. How can I convert my generated output in rows and columns so it will look like this:

```
(0 0) (0 1) (0 2) (0 3) (0 4) (0 5)
(1 0) (1 1) (1 2) (1 3) (1 4) (1 5)
(2 0) (2 1) (2 2) (2 3) (2 4) (2 5)
(3 0) (3 1) (3 2) (3 3) (3 4) (3 5)
(4 0) (4 1) (4 2) (4 3) (4 4) (4 5)
```

The code that i have written so far:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
            {
                if (a == 0)
                {
                    for (int b = 0; b < 6; b++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("({0} {1})", a, b );
                    }

                }

                if (a == 1)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < 6; c++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("({0} {1})", a, c);
                    }
                }

                if (a == 2)
                {
                    for (int d = 0; d < 6; d++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("({0} {1})", a, d);
                    }
                }

                if (a == 3)
                {
                    for (int e = 0; e < 6; e++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("({0} {1})", a, e);
                    }
                }

                if (a == 4)
                {
                    for (int f = 0; f < 6; f++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("({0} {1})", a, f);
                    }
                }

                if (a == 5)
                {
                    for (int g = 0; g < 6; g++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("({0} {1})", a, g);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code is **way** more complex then it needs to be.
There is no need to repeat the same inner loop for each case of a in the outer loop.

Second, you are using `Console.WriteLine` method that appends a NewLine character to everything it writes to the console. use `Console.Write` instead.
Try this:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < 6; b++)
    {
        Console.Write("({0} {1})", a, b );
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```